# Using javascript to fix a page?

Tags: javascript

I have on my site a blog-page on which you can add comments. The fact is that when you click on "add a comment", there is php server request to store the comment. So the page loads again and scrolls to the top. Is there any javascript way to maintain the page fixed when adding the comment ?

Best

Comment: You could add the comment via AJAX, so a page reload never needs to happen. Alternately, you could use anchors in the URL to jump the user back to (almost) the same place.

Comment: Use AJAX to not reload the whole page, or add javascript which scrolls the page to the right position after it is loaded.

Comment: or load the url with a named anchor which is what all professional commenting systems do.

Comment: For sure I know it is possible by AJAX :-) but I am looking for javascript code... Does the jquery method like scrollTop() can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way to do this:

1) use a anchor name after the url request of the page and make an anchor with that name, just above of below the comments.
So redirect to your page with anchor name www.mysite.com/mypage.php#comments and ad an anchor in your html:

```
    <a name="comments" />
```

, this will open the page with the anchor dom element positioned at the top of the screen.

2) sent the data with ajax to the server and update the comments when retrieving a succesfull callback. The page does not need to reload that way and stays where it is. But a bit more work.
step 1: make a php page that handles the request and saves the comment
step 2: add javascript to make a ajax call and retrieve the callback

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use cookies? I have a very similar issue, but regarding textbox. Where, after hitting "Save" (and thus reloading webpage) it always started at first line, not the one, where I ended editing.

The solution was to hire cookies. When user clicked "Save" a simple JavaScript code was writing a cookie with the position on editor, where cursor was. Then, after reload, another simple JavaScript read that cookie and set cursor back to the last position.

Maybe you can adapt this solution to your needs?

Comment: This sounds interesting. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function on your comment button click

```
function FUNCTIONNAME() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOUR METHOD NAME WHICH IS CALLED",
        data: "{PARAMETER VALUES TO BE PASSED}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function () {
        },
        success: function (msg) {                    
           alert("YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE HERE");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Error ");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @madflow naah u can also use JAVASCRIPT and AJAX...i just made i little simple ;)

Comment: I know sorry - your example uses the jQuery object. Thats what I meant ;)